# how to get active tab instantly in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension. Is that possible to get the active tab info in current window instantly rather than using the "chrome.tabs.query()"?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: when you have way to do it with chrome.tabs.query() why would you not want to use it?

Comment: with chrome.tabs.query(), you cannot get it instantly, because there is a callback function there, something wrong with the synchronised problem

Comment: That's how it works with JavaScript code. Suggest you learn to use callbacks as that's how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a timing constraint where you need the active tab immediately (not async) you can maintain a reference to the active tab by listening to active tab changes with [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) e.g.

```
var activeTab;
function updateActive(tab) {
    activeTab = tab;
}
function onActivated(info) {
    chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, updateActive);
}
function onUpdated(info, tab) {
    if (tab.active)
        updateActive(tab);
}
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    updateActive(tabs[0]);
    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(onActivated);
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);
});
```

then when you want to get the tab immediately just use `activeTab`.

NOTE: handling multiple windows is left as an excercise for the reader. see [chrome.windows.onFocusChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged)